# how to add new line using fs.writeFile?

Tags: node.js

I tried to write my project's files to a new file, each one in **new line**, using Node.js. How can I do that? Below is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var colors = require('colors');

fs.readdir('./', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
    fs.writeFile('./new.txt', data, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Saved!'.blue);
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: add `\n` to string?

Comment: `fs.writeFile('./new.txt', data.join('\n'), ...`);

Comment: Thanks Jake it's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all filenames first and then write them to a file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const colors = require('colors');

let fileNames = '';

fs.readdir('./', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    data.forEach(filename => fileNames += filename + '\n');

    fs.writeFile('./new.txt', fileNames, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved!'.blue);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ehem... Don't you think you may want to wait for the readdir to end until it's done? Also readdir returns an array of found filenames, so it won't work like this...